# How to create a function to get 7 words after and before, match of an specific string?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, function

Hello I would like to make a javascript function to return 7 words before and after a math to an specific keyword

I tried as follows:

```
function myFunction(text) {

    b=text.match("(?:[a-zA-Z'-]+[^a-zA-Z'-]+){0,7}"+text+"(?:[^a-zA-Z'-]+[a-zA-Z'-]+){0,7}");

    return b;
```

However when I search in my text "create" I justo got:

```
create
```

My desired output would be:

```
the Community, and view patterns you create or favorite in My Patterns. Explore results
```

My complete code looks as follows, with my corresponding string called Text, so I would like to appreciate the support to overcome this task.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>
<script>


var Text='RegExr was created by gskinner.com, and is proudly hosted by Media Temple. Edit the Expression & Text to see matches. Roll over matches or the expression for details. PCRE & Javascript flavors of RegEx are supported. The side bar includes a Cheatsheet, full Reference, and Help. You can also Save & Share with the Community, and view patterns you create or favorite in My Patterns. Explore results with the Tools below. Replace & List output custom results. Details lists capture groups. Explain describes your expression in plain English.'
function myFunction(text) {

    b=text.match("(?:[a-zA-Z'-]+[^a-zA-Z'-]+){0,7}"+text+"(?:[^a-zA-Z'-]+[a-zA-Z'-]+){0,7}");

    return b; 
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myFunction("create");
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regular expressions aren't a great tool for this type of task. I would recommend using `split` to break your sentence into an array of words and then `indexOf` to find the matching word and print the adjacent words.

Here's a working example:

```js
let sentence = "blah blah blah the Community, and view patterns you create or favorite in My Patterns. Explore results blah blah blah";
let words = sentence.split(" ");
let index = words.indexOf("create");
let result = [];

if (index > -1) {     
    for (i=index-7; i < (index+8); i++) {
        result.push(words[i]);
    }
}
    
console.log(result.join(" "));
```

That's the gist of it, but you'll need to modify my code sample to take into account edge cases (i.e., multiple matching words, less than 7 words preceding/following the matching word).

Comment: @charlietfl Yep, I pointed out in my answer that the OP would need to take my code sample and revise it to cover a few edge cases.

Answer (score 1):

You can split the text into a words array and find the index of the word then use `Array#slice()` and `Array#join()`

Following also removes `.` and `,` punctuation for matching in case that word includes such punctuation before the following space and normalizes case match

```js
var Text = 'RegExr was created by gskinner.com, and is proudly hosted by Media Temple. Edit the Expression & Text to see matches. Roll over matches or the expression for details. PCRE & Javascript flavors of RegEx are supported. The side bar includes a Cheatsheet, full Reference, and Help. You can also Save & Share with the Community, and view patterns you create or favorite in My Patterns. Explore results with the Tools below. Replace & List output custom results. Details lists capture groups. Explain describes your expression in plain English.'

var term = 'create',
  words = Text.split(' '),
  index = words.findIndex(s => s.replace(/,|\.$/, '').toLowerCase() === term.toLowerCase()),
  start = index > 6 ? index - 7 : 0;

var res = words.slice(start, index + 8).join(' ')

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

Some issues with your attempt:

1. Regexes are not strings. If you want to create a regex from a string, you need to use `new RegExp()`
2. The variables are mixed up. It does not help that one variable is called Text and the other text. And so you end up trying to find `text` inside `text`, which obviously is not what you want. So, use distinct variable names, and also pass both of them to the function
3. The word you search ("create") will first match with "created" near the start of the input. As the regex specifies that what follows is all optional (`{0,7}`), this will be considered a match! To avoid this, require that there is at least one word interruption following, or the end of the string. The same for the part that precedes the matching word: it should not be completely optional. Use `{1,7}` and don't require the word part in it (`*`). Give as alternative `^`  or `$` respectively.
4. The `match` method will return an array when there is a match, so you'll want to return the value inside that array (if there is a match).

So with minimal changes, your code could be made to work like this:

```js
var text='RegExr was created by gskinner.com, and is proudly hosted by Media Temple. Edit the Expression & Text to see matches. Roll over matches or the expression for details. PCRE & Javascript flavors of RegEx are supported. The side bar includes a Cheatsheet, full Reference, and Help. You can also Save & Share with the Community, and view patterns you create or favorite in My Patterns. Explore results with the Tools below. Replace & List output custom results. Details lists capture groups. Explain describes your expression in plain English.'
function myFunction(text, find) {
    b = text.match(new RegExp("(?:(?:[a-zA-Z'-]*[^a-zA-Z'-]+){1,7}|^)"+find+"(?:(?:[^a-zA-Z'-]+[a-zA-Z'-]*){1,7}|$)"));
    return b && b[0]; 
}
console.log( myFunction(text, "create") );
```

Be aware that `gskinner.com,` is counted as two distinct words in your regular expression. I assume this was your purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Your regular expression works perfectly for me.

Your hiccup is that you have two variables with similar names: `Text` and `text`.

Change `b=text.match` to `b=Text.match`, because you want to match against the string outside of your function. Currently, you match the expression to a string containing only the desired word.

Something else to look for when you make your change: match returns the first occurrence of `"create"` which happens to be a substring of the third word. You may want to consider modifying the expression to prevent partial matches.

Answer (score 1):

How about this one:

```
(?:\w+[,\.]? ){6}create(?:[\,.]? \w+){7}
```

- `(?:\w+[,\.]? )` is a word followed with a comma or dot optionally and a space
- `{6}` indicated the word will appear 6 times.
- `create` matches self literally
- `(?:[\,.]? \w+){7}` matches 7 words with an optional comma or dot and a space before

Try it out at [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/oxEMsl/5) or check the snippet.

```js
var string = "RegExr was created by gskinner.com, and is proudly hosted by Media Temple. Edit the Expression & Text to see matches. Roll over matches or the expression for details. PCRE & Javascript flavors of RegEx are supported. The side bar includes a Cheatsheet, full Reference, and Help. You can also Save & Share with the Community, and view patterns you create or favorite in My Patterns. Explore results with the Tools below. Replace & List output custom results. Details lists capture groups. Explain describes your expression in plain English.";

var regex = /(?:\w+[,\.]? ){6}create(?:[\,.]? \w+){7}/;
var output = string.match(regex);

console.log(output[0]);
```

The snippet prints:

> the Community, and view patterns you create or favorite in My Patterns. Explore results

---

Edit: At what case do you include the word `create` among the 7 words?

Answer (score 1):

You use a string, where you should use a `RegExp` constructor.

You use the same variable `'text'` to search and match. You want to search `'Text'` and use `'text'` in the regex.

You should add a `'Word boundary`' around your variable to match Words.

**Here's the code:**

```
function myFunction(text) {
    b=Text.match(new RegExp('(?:[a-zA-Z'-]+[^a-zA-Z'-]+){0,7}\b' + text + '\b(?:[^a-zA-Z'-]+[a-zA-Z'-]+){0,7}');
    return b; 
}
```

Hope this Works for you.